# How Can I Find The Path To A Folder from a Controller Constructor in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the path to a folder in my website root and save it to a class property when my controller constructor is called:

```
public TestController:Controller{
    string temp;

    public TestController(){
        temp = "";
        }

    }
```

I have tried the following:

```
temp = Server.MapPath("~/TheFolder/"); // Server is null - error.
temp = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"TheFolder\"; // Request is null - error.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory will give you the root of your site. So:

```
temp = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TheFolder");
```

(Update thanks to Marc Gravell's comment)

Comment: Path.Combine would be nicer ;-p

Comment: this returns the temp folder directory, and it could mean completely wrong folder.

Answer (score 7):

Do you actually need this path during the constructor? If you don't need it until the main page cycle begins, consider deferring it - just using a regular property; something like

```
public string BasePath {
    get { return Server.MapPath("~/TheFolder/"); }
}
```

Then when this is used during the page cycle, it should be fine. You could cache it if you *really* want to, but I don't imagine this is going to be a bottleneck:

```
private string basePath;
public string BasePath {
    get {
        if(basePath == null) basePath = Server.MapPath("~/TheFolder/");
        return basePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I might end up going this route later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try going through the ControllerContext. Forgive my syntax, but it should something like this:

```
base.[Controller?]Context.HttpContext.Server.MapPath();
```

If Server is *still* null in that situation, are you running outside of a web request (ie. in a test)?